# Is SELECT ... FOR UPDATE suitable for a one-time-use row scenario?

Tags: mysql, locking

I have a table of `promo_codes` that can be activated by a web application.  There is a `state` column which can be either 0 for unactivated or 1 for activated.  If I run a transaction with

```
SELECT FROM promo_codes WHERE state=0 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE promo_codes SET state=1 WHERE id = ?;
```

What happens to a second transaction running:

```
SELECT FROM promo_codes WHERE state=0 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;
```

Does it simply return the next row, or does it block until the first transaction is done?

I've actually started thinking about just setting a lock based on the row id in redis because it's obvious to me how that would work and I know it wouldn't create any performance issues in MySQL, but on the other hand, there must be a clean and performant way to make this work purely in SQL.  Maybe I could use just do an `UPDATE ... LIMIT 1` first, but how do I get the id of the promo code back in that case?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT for UPDATE and LOCK IN SHARE MODE modifiers effectively run in READ-COMMITTED isolation mode even if current isolation mode is REPEATABLE-READ. This is done beause Innodb can only lock current version of row. Think about similar case and row being deleted. Even if Innodb would be able to set locks on rows which no more exist – would it do any good for you ? Not really – for example you could try to update the row which you just locked with SELECT FOR UPDATE but this row is already gone so you would get quite unexpected error updating the row which you thought you locked successfully. Anyway it is done this way for good all other decisions would be even more troublesome.

LOCK IN SHARE MODE is actually often used to bypass multiversioning and make sure we’re reading most current data, plus to ensure it can’t be changed. This for example can be used to read set of the rows, compute new values for some of them and write them back. If we would not use LOCK IN SHARE MODE we could be in trouble as rows could be update before we write new values to them and such update could be lost.